# PHP: Simple PDO loop not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Just parsing a file and building a query BUT the `$row` only returns me ***one*** result, where is hold get A result per query i make.

```
while (!feof($f)) {

    $contents = '';
    $contents = fgets($f);
    $p = explode(" ", $contents);

    $req = "SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='".$p[1]."'";


    $rs = $dbh->prepare($req);
    $rs->execute();

    $row  = $rs->fetch();

    print_r($row);
}
```

I am only getting one result at the end

My debug is like this :

```
M0852 

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='M0852 ' ) 

M0850 

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='M0850 ' ) 

M0850 

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='M0850 ' ) 

M0851 

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='M0851 ' ) 

M0851 

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='M0851 ' ) 

M0855 

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='M0855 ' ) 

M0849 

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`='M0849 ' )
```

> Array ( [id_product] => 2662 [0] => 2662 )

when I am expecting to get one array with results per query.

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. By using string concatenation, you are completely bypassing the usefulness of prepared statements.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i understand but i made this with "conventional" bindings same result

Comment: @chris85 each fetch will return one row and its not the point

Comment: Oh so you mean when you use `$row` outside of the loop you want the 1 row per return? `$row[]  = $rs->fetch();`, still could just be done with 1 query though using the `in()`.

Comment: `fetch()` only returns 1 row. If you want all rows, use `fetchAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only the last line in the file don't have a LF character at the end.
use trim() to strip it out

```
$req = "SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE `reference`=?";
$rs = $dbh->prepare($req);
while (!feof($f)) {

    $contents = trim(fgets($f));
    $p = explode(" ", $contents);

    $rs->execute([$p[1]]);
    $row  = $rs->fetch();

    print_r($row);
}
```